# File upload using chunking is giving 500 Internal server error while uploading using php

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

My website is hosted on godaddy and runs on php. I've problem with uploading files using chunking. The problem is only with certain files. One such file is of size 5.13 MB. I'm able to upload much bigger files of size 20 MB and even smaller files. The problem is with only this file. I checked the content and it is not a problem with the content. It is pure .txt file. This file is uploading in 6 chunk and in the 6th chunk it is giving 500 Internal server error. It is able to successfully process files that are divided into around 20 chunks (each chunk size is 1 MB). I tried in chrome and Edge and the same is the problem.
I'm using the following javascript code for chunking and uploading the content. I did lot of googling but my issue seems to be unique and couldn't find a solution anywhere. Most of the answers are referring to 500 error related to file size. But as I mentioned, I'm able to upload bigger files.

```
function sendRequest() {
    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementById('file').files.length; i++) {
        var blob = document.getElementById('file').files[i];
        var BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1048576;//100 * 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunk sizes.
        //var BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // 100MB chunk sizes.
        var SIZE = blob.size;
        var start = 0;
        var end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        //alert(window["uploadcounter" + i]);
        window["uploadcounter" + i]=0;
        window["uploadfilearray" + i] = [];
        document.getElementById('uploadPercent' + i).innerHTML = "Upload: 0 % ";
        while( start < SIZE ) {
            var chunk = blob.slice(start, end);
            window["uploadfilearray" + i][window["uploadcounter" + i]]=chunk;
            window["uploadcounter" + i]=window["uploadcounter" + i]+1;
            start = end;
            end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        }

        window["uploadcounter" + i]=0;
        uploadFile(window["uploadfilearray" + i][window["uploadcounter" + i]], document.getElementById('file').files[i].name, i);
//      setInterval(new function() {updateFileProcessingStatus(document.getElementById('file').files[i].name)}, 3000);
    }
}

var chunkNumber = 0;

function uploadFile(blobFile, filename, fileIndex) {
    alert(blobFile.size + '        chunknumber: ' + ++chunkNumber);

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("fileToUpload", blobFile);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();



    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

    xhr.open("POST", "./datafileupload.php?filename="+filename + "&chunkNumber=" + chunkNumber + "&r=" + Math.random());

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        window["uploadcounter" + fileIndex] = window["uploadcounter" + fileIndex] + 1;
        if(window["uploadfilearray" + fileIndex].length > window["uploadcounter" + fileIndex] ){
            uploadFile(window["uploadfilearray" + fileIndex][window["uploadcounter" + fileIndex]], filename, fileIndex); 
            var percentloaded2 = parseInt((window["uploadcounter" + fileIndex]/window["uploadfilearray" + fileIndex].length)*100);
            $('#uploadPercent' + fileIndex).html('Upload Percent : '+ filename + ' ' + percentloaded2+' % ');
            $('#progressbar' + fileIndex).attr('style', 'width:' + percentloaded2 + '%');
        }else{
            $('#progressbar' + fileIndex).attr('style', 'width: 100%');
            $('#uploadPercent' + fileIndex).html("File uploaded");
            processFile(filename);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(fd);

}
```

Also on the other side the following is the php code handling the uploaded file

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 10000); 
    require("dbconfig.php");
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
    if ((!isset($_SESSION['newsession']) || $_SESSION['newsession'] == false) && $_SESSION["ROLE"] == 'Admin'){
        $name2 = $_GET['filename'];
        echo "the chunk received is " . $_GET["chunkNumber"];

        $extension = end((explode(".", $name2)));
        if($extension != 'csv' || $extension != 'txt') {
            exit;
        }
        $lowerCaseName = strtolower($name2);
        $isValidCSV = 0;
        if(strpos($lowerCaseName, "gsa") !== false) {
            $isValidCSV = 1;
        } else if(strpos($lowerCaseName, "product") !== false) {
            $isValidCSV = 1;
        } else if(strpos($lowerCaseName, "image") !== false) {
            $isValidCSV = 1;
        } else if(strpos($lowerCaseName, "supplier") !== false) {
            $isValidCSV = 1;
        } else if(strpos($lowerCaseName, "account") !== false) {
            $isValidCSV = 1;
        }
        if($isValidCSV === 0) {
            exit;
        }
        $name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
        $target_path = "./uploadedfiles/";
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];

        $target_file = $target_path.$name;
        $complete =$target_path.$name2;
        $com = fopen($complete, "ab");
        error_log($target_path);

        // Open temp file
        //$out = fopen($target_file, "wb");

        //if ( $out ) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = fopen($tmp_name, "rb");
            if ( $in ) {
                while($buff = fread( $in, 1048576 )) {
                    fwrite($com, $buff);
                }   
            }
            fclose($in);

        //}
        //fclose($out);
        fclose($com);
    }else{
        echo'you are not logged in.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I did some more analysis on this. On godaddy site my max_post_size is 128 MB. I'm uploading files by splitting them to 1MB size chunks. However when the last chunk is slightly more than 128 KB, configurations on godaddy site are comparing this >128 KB with 128 MB (only values are compared without consideration to Unit...so they're comparing the KB with MB) and throwing a 500 Internal Server Error. Their support team is not able to accept this fact and asking me to check the php scripts and it could be problem with the scripts. But as you can see, there is nothing wrong with the scripts.

Comment: godaddy is such a bad hosting. I'm also struggling with them.